# Show full hostname in bash?

Tags: debian, hostname

Any way to show full hostname in bash instead of partial?

Now for `domain.com` it's:

`user@domain:~$`

Would like it to be:

`user@domain.com:~$`

Debian 8.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bash prompt is configured by the `PS1` variable. You can configure it simply by setting the variable for example like this:

```
export PS1="$(hostname -f):~$ "
```

If you want to make the configuration permanent you can put the `export` command in your `~/.bashrc` file.

I recommend reading the [ArchWiki Page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization) for more information.

Comment: seems that changing `\h` to `\H` worked aswell... anyway... how do I set it up so it would automatically use modified `bashrc` on `adduser`?

Comment: Configuration files for new users are stored under `/etc/skel`. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26607/how-do-i-set-a-users-default-bashrc-file

Answer (score 3):

For Debian 10 open file located at: /etc/bash.bashrc

change 21st line from:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

to:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\H:\w\$
```

\h becomes \H

then do following command:

```
source /etc/bash.bashrc
```

or restart your bash session/relogin.